# ¿Tengo el problema de ciclado de dependencias en mi proyecto spring 2.7.4 como puedo resolverlo?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación con spring, quiero poder validar que el token de un usuario sea el dueño del mismo, para eso tengo lo siguiente y manda este error de ciclado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el codigo siguiente:

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    InfoAdicionalToken infoAdicionalToken;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")//damos permisos publicos a la ruta para generar el token, sino como van a genera token
        .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()"); //Datos permisos publicos para validar el token, sino como van a genera token
    }
    
    

    
    
    //Aqui asignamos las firmas del token
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PRIVADA);
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setVerifierKey(JwtConfig.RSA_PUBLICA);
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
```

Parece que el problema está en esta clase:

```
public class InfoAdicionalToken implements TokenEnhancer{

    @Autowired
    private UsuariosTrUsuarioService usuariosTrUsuarioService;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        
        Optional<UsuariosTrUsuario>  user = usuariosTrUsuarioService.findByDsCorreo(authentication.getName());
        
        Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
        info.put("tkpnt", JwtLegacyConfig.buildJWT(user.get().getDsCorreo(), user.get().getIdUsuario()));
        info.put("mb", user.get().getIdUsuario());
        info.put("nombre", user.get().getDsNombre());
        info.put("primerApellido",user.get().getDsPrimerApellido());
        info.put("segundoApellido", user.get().getDsSegundoApellido());
        info.put("correo", user.get().getDsCorreo());
        
        
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);
        
        return accessToken;
    }
    
    
    
    public Long validarUsuarioConToken(OAuth2Authentication auth) {
        final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        //token
        String accessTokenPeticion = details.getTokenValue();
        
        OAuth2AccessToken t = tokenStore.readAccessToken(accessTokenPeticion);
        Map<String, Object> infoTOK = t.getAdditionalInformation();
        Integer idUsuario =  (Integer) infoTOK.get("mb");
        Long id =  Long.valueOf(idUsuario);
        return id;
    }
```

Este es el error que me manda :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba agregar la anotación @Lazy a la inyección `InfoAdicionalToken infoAdicionalToken;` en la clase `AuthorizationServerConfig `

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente agregando la anotacion @Lazy , mil gracias!